Newcommand for Comment Footnotes Not Displaying Properly When Used in a Chapter Title
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\textheight=6.25in \textwidth 4.25in \oddsidemargin=-.375in \evensidemargin=-.375in


% To produce a comment [unnumbered] footnote with \commentfootnote command.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\commentfootnote}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \addtocounter{footnote}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}%
  \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


% Positioning Chapters, Sections, Subsections.
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\centering}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\huge}
%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\centering}
%  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{20pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-5pt}{-10pt}{3pt}
% {}{}{} LEFT, TOP, BELOW


\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents


\chapter[Title of Chapter I.]{Title of Chapter I.\commentfootnote{*}{Chapter Title comment footnote.}}

This is a sentence.\footnote{Ordinary footnote.}

\noindent This is another sentence.\commentfootnote{*}{Ordinary comment footnote.}
\end{document}

which produces:

QUESTION: Why is the footnotemark for the first footnote below not an asterisk? My command, \commentfootnote seems to work fine when used in a paragraph, but not in a chapter title. What I am expecting below the footnote line are three footnote marks: The first and last being asterisks, and the second being "1".
Thank you.

Just a note: Without titlesec it works.

@cabohah In the actual document, I need titlesec. I am hoping there might be a way to   correct the problem and still keep titlesec. Thanks for your comment.

What's the reason for using geometry and later setting \evensidemargin and friends by hand, which is difficult?

This seems to be a problem using package titlesec. An alternative to using titlesec would be to use classes that already support configuration of headings, e.g., the KOMA-Script class scrbook. You can configure this class to look similar to the standard class book and also reconfigure the style of the chapter, section etc. titles. Here an example:
\documentclass[12pt,openany,chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,footskip=2\baselineskip,headheight=12pt,headsep=20pt]{geometry}% Three values added to adapt book.
\textheight=6.25in \textwidth 4.25in \oddsidemargin=-.375in \evensidemargin=-.375in% Note: This overwrites several of the settings above


% To produce a comment [unnumbered] footnote with \commentfootnote command.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\commentfootnote}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \addtocounter{footnote}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}%
  \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=46pt,% must be larger than 30pt, because titlesec adds extra space
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=24pt,
  font=\sffamily\huge,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  ]{chapter}
\let\raggedchapter\centering
  
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=20pt,
  afterskip=5pt,
  ]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  indent=-5pt,% IMHO DOESN'T MAKE SENSE, BUT YOU'VE USED IT
  beforeskip=-10pt,% IMHO DOESN'T MAKE SENSE, BUT YOU'VE USED IT
  afterskip=3pt
  ]{subsection}

\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}

% And to use page styles similar to book class:
\usepackage[automark,pagestyleset=standard,autoenlargeheadfoot=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents


\chapter[Title of Chapter I.]{Title of Chapter I.\commentfootnote{*}{Chapter Title comment footnote.}}

This is a sentence.\footnote{Ordinary footnote.}

\noindent This is another sentence.\commentfootnote{*}{Ordinary comment
  footnote.}

\section{Testsection}

And the text below.

\subsection{Subsection}

And the text below.

\end{document}

To make the results comparable, the following shows on the left side the result with your code using book (extended by a section and a subsection) and on the right side with scrbook.

The package scrlayer-scrpage was only used to adapt the page header and footer to the style of book. Of course, you can also use this package for other changes to the page style. For more information, please refer to the KOMA-Script manuals.
For more information on configuration of the scrbook class, also see the KOMA-Script manual.
